# Creating multi-OS boot CD using codes

Tags: iso, live-cd

Is it possible to write coding that will allows one to store multiple OS (in their ISO format) into a CD/DVD and turn them into a Live CD/DVD for later use?

Comment: Is it possible to tell me more about it? (e.g. giving links showing that someone did it before?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  You would probably want to use [Grub4DOS](https://gna.org/projects/grub4dos/) as your boot loader because it can boot operating systems from disk images, which, to my knowledge, other boot loaders don't do.  So you could potentially load up a DVD-ROM with Grub4DOS and several live CD isos so that you could then boot multiple operating systems from that DVD-ROM.

Comment: From what I understand, Grub4DOS does not boot up certain OS in their ISO format - do correct me if I understand wrongly.

Comment: Bootloaders do not discriminate based on operating system in terms of which they load.  Operating systems are binary programs.  The boot loader just has to know where the binary program which represents the operating system is and load it into memory and start it.  The operating system takes over from there.  In any bootloader, you can specify the file path of the binary for any file system it supports.

The boot loader itself has to be installed on the drive and there are limits to which operating system can be used to install it.  That might be where you're getting confused.

Comment: I do agree that there are limits to which operating system can be used to install it cause certain OS just cannot mix with other OS.